# Form submitting even response is true or false in Ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a text box(facebook link field),i am using ajax with "jquery on blur event",
Everything is working fine but the problem is, if returns an error 
then the form should not be submitted untill a new correct link is given (success msg/green text)
I tried with following way,How can i solve this ?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Facebook Profile Link" name="facebook_link" id="facebook_link">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#facebook_link").blur(function(){
    var fb = $("#facebook_link").val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type:"post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/check_fb",
        data:{ fb:fb},
        success:function(response)
        {
        if($.trim(response) == "true")
            {
                $('#msg').html('<span style="color:green;">Valid Facebook Link</span>');

            }
            else 
            {
                $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red;">Link is invalid</span>');
                return false;
            }  
        }
    });

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please post whole code.

Comment: Who is submitting _anything_ here? You are only reacting to a blur event, what’s that got to do with actually submitting anything?